# Using Facebook graph API, error when trying to get friends list

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using PHP with the Facebook PHP SDK

My code:

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
```

I am successfully able to log in with Facebook account, but I am having trouble getting the user friends list.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
//Get friends list

$session = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/taggable_friends',
  array(
    'fields' => 'name,picture'
  )
);
```

I took this code from Facebook graph explorer and over there its working perfectly.

I am getting the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to `Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct()` must be an instance of `Facebook\FacebookApp`, `string` given, called in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/index.php` on line 76 and defined in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php` on line 97

What am i doing wrong, and is it ok what I have done with the $session variable?

Comment: I cleaned up some of the grammar in the post, and added some formatting to make it easier for people to answer, and so it's a more useful reference for future users.  I also removed the 'Thank You' at the end. For more information about thank yous please see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use an App instance, right now you are only using a string as the error message tells you. Here´s the relevant part of the official docs, with example code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0

I suggest upgrading to v5.0 of the PHP SDK, it comes with the same server requirements anyway.

Comment: then you made the same mistake. the error message is very clear, you are using a string where you need to use an app instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request` factory provided by the `\Facebook\Facebook` class:
`$fb->request($method, $endpoint);`

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0#request